# Virtual event handlers from several classes: multiple inheritance or composition?

Tags: c++, oop, event-handling, multiple-inheritance, composition

My team has written several C++ classes which implement event handling via pure virtual callbacks - for example, when a message is received from another process, the base class which handles IPC messaging calls its own pure virtual function, and a derived class handles the event in an override of that function.  The base class knows the event has occurred; the derived class knows what to do with it.

I now want to combine the features provided by these base classes in a higher-level class, so for example when a message arrives from another process, my new class can then forward it on over its network connection using a similar event-driven networking class.  It looks like I have two options:

- (1) composition: derive classes from each of the event-handling base classes and add objects of those derived classes to my new class as members, or:
- (2) multiple inheritance: make my new class a derived class of all of the event-handling base classes.

I've tried both (1) and (2), and I'm not satisfied with my implementation of either.

There's an extra complication: some of the base classes have been written using initialisation and shutdown methods instead of using constructors and destructors, and of course these methods have the same names in each class.  So multiple inheritance causes function name ambiguity.  Solvable with `using` declarations and/or explicit scoping, but not the most maintainable-looking thing I've ever seen.

Even without that problem, using multiple inheritance and overriding every pure virtual function from each of several base classes is going to make my new class very big, bordering on "God Object"-ness.  As requirements change (read: "as requirements are added") this isn't going to scale well.

On the other hand, using separate derived classes and adding them as members of my new class means I have to write lots of methods on each derived class to exchange information between them.  This feels very much like "getters and setters" - not quite as bad, but there's a lot of "get this information from that class and hand it to this one", which has an inefficient feel to it - lots of extra methods, lots of extra reads and writes, and the classes have to know a lot about each other's logic, which feels wrong.  I think a full-blown publish-and-subscribe model would be overkill, but I haven't yet found a simple alternative.

There's also a lot of duplication of data if I use composition.  For example, if my class's state depends on whether its network connection is up and running, I have to either have a state flag in every class affected by this, or have every class query the networking class for its state every time a decision needs to be made.  If I had just one multiply-inherited class, I could just use a flag which any code in my class could access.

So, multiple inheritance, composition, or perhaps something else entirely?  Is there a general rule-of-thumb on how best to approach this kind of thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description I think you've gone for a "template method" style approach where the base does work and then calls a pure virtual that the derived class implements rather than a "callback interface" approach which is pretty much the same except that the pure virtual method is on a completely separate interface that's passed in to the "base" as a parameter to the constructor. I personally prefer the later as I find it considerably more flexible when the time comes to plug objects together and build higher level objects.

I tend to go for composition with the composing class implementing the callback interfaces that the composed objects require and then potentially composing again in a similar style at a higher level.

You can then decide if it's appropriate to compose by having the composing object implement the callback interfaces and pass them in to the "composed" objects in their constructors OR you can implement the callback interface in its own object possibly with a simpler and more precise callback interface that your composing object implements, and compose both the "base object" and the "callback implementation object"...

Personally I wouldn't go with an "abstract event handling" interface as I prefer my code to be explicit and clear even if that leads to it being slightly less generic.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally clear on what your new class is trying to achieve, but it sounds like you're effectively having to provide a new implementation somewhere for all of these abstract event classes.

Personally I would plump for composition. Multiple inheritance quickly becomes a nightmare, especially when things have to change, and composition keeps the existing separation of concerns.

You state that each derived object will have to communicate with the network class, but can you try and reduce this to the minimum. For instance, each derived event object is purely responsible for packaging up the event info into some kind of generic packet, and then that packet is passed to the network class to do the guts of sending?

Without knowing exactly what your new class is doing it's hard to comment, or suggest better patterns, but the more I code, the more I am learning to agree with the old adage "favour composition over inheritance"